# Apple Mach O Link Key failed when compiling GooglsMaps.Framework

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3

I have tried to add all `GoogleMaps.Framework` and `GoogleMaps.bundle` at the framework
When it comes to the execution, it causes the following error

I have no clue on what happens exactly. Would you please tell me the proper way to add `Google MAP SDK frameworks` instead ?

I have even added the framework libc++.dylib.

The error message

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex", referenced from:
      _GMSCreateCGImageWithData in GoogleMaps(GMMImageSupport.o)
  "_CGImageSourceCreateWithDataProvider", referenced from:
      _GMSCreateCGImageWithData in GoogleMaps(GMMImageSupport.o)
  "_GLKMatrix3Identity", referenced from:
      gmscore::vector::GLLineGroup::SetTransform(gmscore::math::Matrix4f const&, gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::vector::Camera> const&) in GoogleMaps(GLLineGroup.o)
  "_GLKMatrix4Invert", referenced from:
      -[GMSStreetViewView fadeOutLastScene] in GoogleMaps(GMSStreetViewView.o)
      gmscore::streetview::Camera::Unproject(gmscore::math::Vector2f const&, bool*) const in GoogleMaps(Camera-B046EE312980DB98.o)
      gmscore::vector::Camera::UpdateInternals() in GoogleMaps(Camera-3E3856CABC8A9C74.o)
      gmscore::renderer::Camera3D::SetTransform(gmscore::math::Matrix4f const&) in GoogleMaps(Camera3D.o)
      gmscore::renderer::Camera3D::Transform() in GoogleMaps(Camera3D.o)
      non-virtual thunk to gmscore::renderer::Camera3D::Transform() in GoogleMaps(Camera3D.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Double check if you have all these frameworks on your Xcode Project

```
AVFoundation.framework
CoreData.framework
CoreLocation.framework
CoreText.framework
GLKit.framework
ImageIO.framework
libc++.dylib
libicucore.dylib
libz.dylib
OpenGLES.framework
QuartzCore.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
```

Please visit:-
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#getting_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios

to learn step by step instructions on **Adding the Google Maps SDK for iOS to your project**.

Most likely you forget to add `ImageIO.framework`